# Pandas DataFrame - Creating dynamic number of columns

Tags: python, database, pandas, numpy, dataframe

**Data:**

```
    qid     qualid  val
0   1845631864  227     0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1   1899053658  44  1,3,3,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5
2   1192887045  197     704
3   1833579269  194     139472
4   1497352469  30  120026,170154,152723,90407,63119,80077,178871,...
```

**Problem:**

Numbers separated by commas in column **val** need to represented in different columns for each row.

I don't know if Pandas allows for it, but ideally, one would want to create exact **n** number of columns for each row, where **n** is the number of elements in column **val**.

If that is not possible, the greatest number of elements in val should be the number of columns and rows where elements are lesser than that should consist of NaNs.

**Example Solution 1 for Above Problem:**

```
    qid       qualid  val1  val2  val3        valn-3 valn-2 valn-1 valn
0   1845631864  227     0     0    0    ......  0        0      0    0
1   1899053658  44      1     3    3    ......  5
2   1192887045  197    704
3   1833579269  194   139472
4   1497352469  30    120026 170154 152723.....63119  80077 178871 12313
```

**Alternate Solution 2 for Above Problem:**

```
    qid       qualid  val1  val2  val3        valn-3 valn-2 valn-1 valn
0   1845631864  227     0     0    0    ......  0        0      0    0
1   1899053658  44      1     3    3    ......  5      NaN    NaN   NaN
2   1192887045  197    704   NaN  NaN   ...... NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN
3   1833579269  194   139472 NaN  NaN   ...... NaN     NaN    NaN   
4   1497352469  30    120026 170154 152723.....63119  80077 178871 12313
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check `str.split`

```
pd.concat([df,df.val.str.split(',',expand=True).add_prefix('Val_')],axis=1)
Out[29]: 
          qid  qualid  ...   Val_16 Val_17
0  1845631864     227  ...        0      0
1  1899053658      44  ...        5      5
2  1192887045     197  ...     None   None
3  1833579269     194  ...     None   None
4  1497352469      30  ...     None   None
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Cheers.